# Prevent SQL Injection and using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, parameters, sqlcommand, sqldataadapter

So I get to run an application fine inside VB.Net, the folling code is:

```
Private Sub LoadAttachments()
        tablegrid = New DataTable
        myConn = New SqlConnection("Server=CEDASDSOBSQL02\dev; Database=Insurance; Integrated Security=true")
        myConn.Open()
        myCmd = myConn.CreateCommand
        Dim query As String = "SELECT DocType, docyear, CASE WHEN docmonth IS NULL THEN NULL " & _
                  "WHEN docmonth = '0' THEN '- All Months -' WHEN docmonth >= 1 AND docmonth <= 12 " & _
                  "THEN DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, docmonth, -1)) END DocMonth, DID from dbo.Document where XALASKAID = '" & LicenseNumber & "' and DOCTYPE like '%Report%'"
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(query, myConn)
        myCmd = New SqlCommand(query, myConn)
        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        da = New SqlDataAdapter(myCmd)
        da.Fill(tablegrid)
        DataGridView3.DataSource = tablegrid
        Label4.Text = "Found " & DataGridView3.Rows.Count & " images"
    End Sub
```

So this code is a SQL Injection `XALASKAID = '" & LicenseNumber & "'` and that is inside the query. Instead of using `'" & LicenseNumber & "'`  I need to change it something like: `@LicNum` then add `myCmd.Parameters.Add("@LicID", SqlDbType.Int)
myCmd.Parameters("@LicID").Value = LicenseNumber`

All I am getting in the LicenseNumber using the Parameter is null or empty. Also I need some assistant in my code I think I am reusing too many coding. If is possible to simplify a little bit, thank you.

PS: I have all my declaration as Global.

Comment: you might show *how* you are using a Parameter for LicenseNumber

Comment: You've shown us the code that's working (but SQL-injectable), and you're asking us why other code that you haven't shown us isn't working?

Comment: The code above works fine, problem is we cant use  `'" & LicenseNumber & "'` inside the query, instead I'm suppost to use  `@LicID` to prevent SQL Injection. when ever I define the `myCmd.Parameters.Add("@LicID", SqlDbType.Int)
myCmd.Parameters("@LicID").Value = LicenseNumber` Doesn't work when ever I try to call `@LicID` in the query. Also `LicenseNumber` is a variable set as String that hold the value as global from a textbox called txtlicnum.

Comment: are you wanting us to beg for the actual code you need help with?

Comment: No I don't need no one to beg for the code. I notice this forum, people don't have matters, you can't refer to everyone as an expert matter in this topics, that's why they created forums. I'm new to coding and I'm trying to figure out some stuff, But I believe 10% is the one that help. the rest just argue by mistake or not putting correctly the post. English is my second language, probably a lot of here English is second language. But any way thank you I figure out the mistake and I will re-post it as the fix for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had mismatch definition in my original code, I did some removal and changes.

```
Private Sub LoadAttachments()
        attachmentsTable = New DataTable

        Dim mAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        If LicenseNumber IsNot Nothing Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(InsCommonLib.Settings.MSSqlConStr) Then
                Dim query As String = "SELECT DocType, docyear, CASE WHEN docmonth IS NULL THEN NULL " & _
                          "WHEN docmonth = '0' THEN '- All Months -' WHEN docmonth >= 1 AND docmonth <= 12 " & _
                          "THEN DATENAME(month, DATEADD(month, docmonth, -1)) END DocMonth, DID from dbo.Document where XALASKAID = @LICNUM and DOCTYPE like '%Report%'"

                Using mConn As New SqlConnection(InsCommonLib.Settings.MSSqlConStr)
                    Using mCmd As New SqlCommand(query, mConn)
                        mCmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LICNUM", LicenseNumber))
                        mConn.Open()
                        mAdapter.SelectCommand = mCmd
                        mAdapter.Fill(attachmentsTable)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End If

        End If

        DataGridView3.DataSource = attachmentsTable
        Label4.Text = "Found " & DataGridView3.Rows.Count & " images"
    End Sub
```

Thank you for the help and time.